# wordpress Next Post Link not working as expected

Tags: wordpress

So i've been looking at a few post before about next_post_link() ... and its not working as expected. this is what i have:

```
next_post_link("%link");
```

so this will literally come up as :

```
<a href="http://localhost/test-site/blog/test-post-title/" rel="next">test post title</a>
```

So what i want to do is change the a tag text "test post title" to something like "newer post". but the problem it comes auto filled with the text from the post url.

Anyone know how to change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check the:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/214639/changing-next-and-previous-post-link-text

```
<?php previous_post_link( '%link','Previous Post' ) ?>
<?php next_post_link( '%link','Next Post' ) ?>
```